# How to refer to attributes in Ruby/Rails specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to follow these guidelines to write my specs:
[Better Specs](http://betterspecs.org/)

In Ruby it is a convention to refer to class methods using `.method_name` or `::method_name`, and use `#method_name` for instance methods. Does the same convention apply to Rails model attributes?

For instance, should my spec be written like this:

`describe ' #exam_code should be unique'`?

Comment: I tend to put model associations and validations within their own context, because I feel like they are their own aspect of the model. Therefore I would do a `describe "validations"`, and inside I would add `it "require a unique exam code"`. Often you can use the RSpec one liners too, `it { should validate_presence_of(:exam_code) }`.

Comment: Interesting, but does `shoulda` provide matchers for `validate_uniqueness_of` or something like that? I have some other kinds of validations as well.

Comment: It does indeed! See [this page](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel). Careful though: the `validate_uniqueness_of` matcher attempts to create an existing record in the database first, putting in nil for all the attributes it doesn't care about. This can cause it to fail if you don't allow nil values, so you may just have to create a record first for that particular test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this style guide https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#rspec

```
describe '#some_attr' do
  it 'is required' do
    #your spec
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok. I'm also gonna start using this style: `article.should have(1).error_on(:title)`.

Comment: You should do something like "expect(article.error_on(:title)).not_to be_empty", since "expect().to" is the new desired syntax when using rspec. I guess that style guide is not updated.

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't tried `article.should have(1).error_on(:title)` yet, but I see your point. Nevertheless, I think `expect(article).to have(1).error_on(:title)` would be more idiomatic (assuming it is a valid syntax).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that, yes, you should follow the RoR convention for attributes.  Think about it from this perspective: an 'attribute' in Rails is simply a convenient way to automatically create accessor *methods*.

As for the rspec, I prefer the approach that has been described above, placing the attributes within their own describe block.  I'd typically approach it like this:

```
describe Test do
  subject { Test.new(exam_code: exam_code) }
  let(:exam_code) { 'test1' }

  describe '#exam_code' do
    context 'when nil' do
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to put the method name in the describe clause and the condition on it in the it clause as follows:

```
describe :exam_code do
  it "should be unique" do
    #spec code here
  end
end
```